# Split two strings by delimiter and find the first common value

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have two strings with a delimiter. I would like to understand what is the efficient way to split the strings by the delimiter and find the first shared value.

For example:

```
String one = "the;boy;is;six;years;old"
String two = "today;is;sunday"
```

The result is the string `"is"`.

**I thought of the following two ways:**

1. using split method

   ```
   public String match (String one, String two) {
       String[] oneArray = one.split(";");
       String[] twoArray = two.split(";");

       for (String value1 : oneArray){
           for(String value2 : twoArray){
               if(value1.equals(value2)[
                   return value1;
               }
           }
       }
       return "";
   }
   ```
2. using regex

   ```
   public static final Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("\\;");

   private boolean match(String one, String two) {

       Matcher matcherOne = pattern.matcher(one);
       Matcher matcherTwo = pattern.matcher(two);

       //NOT SURE WHAT IS THE IMPLEMENTATION
       if (matcherOne.find().equals(matcherTwo.find()) {

       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks,What is the correct way for splitting the strings and look for the value? if using regex, then how I should use it?

Comment: use natural API, if want split, use split

Comment: Your pattern only describes delimiter. Also matcher can be used to apply pattern to one string at a time. Why would you want to use Pattern/Matcher here? I agree with @JacekCz, if you want to split something use `split` method. Pattern also allows us to split on regex representing delimiter in a way `String[] tokens = yourDelimiterPattern.split(text)` but I am not sure if that is what you are asking about.

Comment: @Pshemo I want after the split to check if the value exists by using contains. which do not exist in String[]. I do not want to go over the array again.